# Visual Studio multiple copy and paste issue

Tags: visual-studio, copy-paste

I hold `CTRL-Shift-` and then press `V` multiple times to paste from a list of my previous few pastes. [not sure what the upper limit of this list is].

My problem is that whenever I remove a line with `CTRL-Delete` Visual Studio replaces my whole lists of pastes with the line which i removed with the `CTRL-Delete`.

Any ideas?

Another thing: how do I traverse back up the list of pastes. (pressing V each time goes down the list ... how do I get back up?)

I'm using VS 2012 if that makes a difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove a line with Ctrl+Shift+L without copying it to clipboard

(I use Ctrl+L to remove a line and copy it to clipboard, so we might not have the same shortcut settings)

/Robert